# how to remove sessions in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to remove a basic session but it's not removing. Here's the code

*welcome.blade.php*

```
@if(Session::has('key'))             
    {{ Session::get('key')}}
    <a href="logout">Sign Out</a>

    @else
        please signin

    @endif
</div>
```

I don't know how to remove session. Here's the one I used but it's not working `route.php`

```
Route::get('/logout', function() {

   $vv =  Session::forget('key');
   if($vv)
   {
        return "signout";
   }
});
```

Comment: You should really use Laravel's built in authentification: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication

Comment: can you show me a example for login and logout

Comment: First read the documentation I linked, second search online for other resources (tutorials, SO questions, etc) and if you still haven't found anything, ask me again. As developer one of the most important skills is to do research and know where to find information. Especially with such basic questions it is pretty easy to find something online.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You should use this method

```
 Route::get('/logout', function() {
 Session::forget('key');
  if(!Session::has('key'))
   {
      return "signout";
   }
 });
```

Comment: How do I do this automatically after a specific time interval, delete specific session key after set time interval. Not the entire session.

Answer (score 8):

You can try with `Session::pull('key');`

And if you want to delete all sessions variable you can use `Session::flush();`

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session#session-usage

Answer (score 2):

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

    class StudentRecord extends Controller
       {

    public function logout(Request $req)
        {
     if($req-session()->has('key'){
              $req->session()->forget('key');
        return redirect('/');
              }

//Or simple
    public function logout(Request $req)
        {
     //if($req-session()->has('key')
         $req->session()->flush();
         }


    }


    //Then Do this in your route file
      Route:get("/logout",StudentRecord@logout);

        <a href=" {{ url(logout)}}">logout</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Session::forget()` does not return true/false. You can just remove your `if` statement.

As a side note, if you're only using the `user` key in `Session` for storing the currently logged in user, you can just use `Auth::user()` instead.

Comment: It is all pretty well documented in the official docs: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication

Comment: `Too few arguments to function Illuminate/Session/Store::forget(), 0 passed in /home/vagrant/code/uscutter/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Manager.php on line 144 and exactly 1 expected`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Request` parameter, containing the current session. This way you can delete any session value by the key:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::get('/logout', function(Request $request) {
        //Uncomment to see the logs record
        //\Log::info("Session before: ".print_r($request->session()->all(), true));
        if ($request->session()->has('key')) {
           $request->session()->forget('key');
        }
        //Uncomment to see the logs record
        //\Log::info("Session after: ".print_r($request->session()->all(), true));
        return redirect('/');
    });
```

Or you can delete all values in the session:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::get('/logout', function(Request $request) {
        //Uncomment to see the logs record
        //\Log::info("Session before: ".print_r($request->session()->all(), true));
        $request->session()->flush();
        //Uncomment to see the logs record
        //\Log::info("Session after: ".print_r($request->session()->all(), true));
        return redirect('/');
    });
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session#using-the-session